# vb.net linq to xml syntax for documents with xml namespace

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to grasp the linq to xml 'inline query syntax' features of VB.Net

First I tried with this simple xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <Root>
       <Child Name="somename">
          <SomeAttribute>SomeValue</SomeAttribute>
       </Child>
    </Root>
```

This xml, when loaded in an XDocument, can be loaded and queried as follows:

```
    Dim xdoc = XDocument.Load("sample.xml")
    Console.WriteLine(xml.Root.<Child>.@Name)
```

Then I change the `<Root>` element in the sample xml file to:

```
    <Root xmlns="http://SomeNamespace">
```

Now I can't seem to use the convenient 'Axis Properties' syntax anymore... I can only get it to work with the explicit XElement syntax:

```
    Dim ns As XNamespace = "http://SomeNamespace"
    ' works, but I would like to use the same syntax as above...
    Console.WriteLine(xdoc.Descendants(ns + "Child").First().Attribute("Name").Value)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384655.aspx)

At first, I didn't know this syntactic feature was called "Axis Properties".

I had to add an Imports statement for the xml namespace:

```
Imports <xmlns:ns="http://SomeNamespace">
```

Then you can query with:

```
xdoc.Root.<ns:Child>.@Name
```